# Input doesn't enable button

Tags: flex-monkey

In my app, a user has to enter at least one character in the password Text Input in order to enable the login button.

If I record the event using FlexMonkey, I see this:

SelectedText: 'password' (0,0)
Input: 'password' (myPassword)

But the button doesn't get enabled when I run it from FlexMonkey. What is happening here?

Any helpful clues will be very much appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: There is a validator attached to the password TextInput and only a 'keyUp' event fires a validator. Can I trigger a 'keyUp' event from FlexMonkey?

Comment: From researching, it seems like I need to instrument the 'keyUp' event from inside my app. Anyone have any experience with instrumenting existing events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Potentially, Flex Monkey is not interacting with the UI or say firing UI events

for me, I always use text change event to capture such kind of things.

Comment: but the 'change' event won't trigger the validator; only 'keyUp'. from reading, it appears that many low-level events are explicitly ignored by FlexMonkey so as to not clutter the interface. however, you can add events back in so FlexMonkey picks it up...but I can't quite figure out how to do it.

Comment: @fumeng I think the validator could be configured to be triggered on specific event.